# Symfony Twig: Truncate undefined characters from string

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I got a string from DB that return the address of an user, I want truncate the first part of this leaving only the City and Country.

Stored strig is like:

```
514 S. Magnolia St. - 32806 - Orlando - FL
```

I want it to be:

```
Orlando - FL
```

How I can do using Twig? I got the datas fetching an object using Doctrine

```
public function profileAction($query)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
    ->find($query);

    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'User '. $user . ' not found.'
        );
    }

    return $this->render('profile/profile.html.twig', [
        'user_info'=>$user,
        ]);
}
```

I'm getting the values using regular Twig: `{{ user_info.address }}`

Comment: `{{ ('514 S. Magnolia St. - 32806 - Orlando - FL' | split('-', 3))[2] }}`

Comment: That's perfect! thanks! post as a reply and I will mark as replied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your format of the address is always the same you can rely on the [split](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) filter of `Twig`, which works the same way as [explode](http://php.net/explode) in PHP

```
{{ ('514 S. Magnolia St. - 32806 - Orlando - FL' | split('-', 3))[2] }}
```

Comment: Thanks I will make sure the format will be always the same merging the registration form data in that way